# Add Widget to Tkinter colorchooser

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

As far as I understand, it is not possible to modify the `tkinter.colorchooser.askcolor` as it uses the systems colorpicker dialog. Is this true?

from the source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/tkinter/colorchooser.py

```
# this module provides an interface to the native color dialogue
# available in Tk 4.2 and newer.
```

The reason being is I wish to add an entry box to the dialog so that I would get the color code and user-entered text returned. Maybe it is possible to embed the dialog within a larger window? Is something like this possible, without using multiple windows?

I cannot find previous discussion anywhere else so I guess it is not a simple issue.

Comment: Unless you implement your own colour chooser, it is not possible

Comment: I might need a colour chooser for my future projects. If you give me some basic designs of what you need, I will try to make it from scratch. As I will be making it from scratch you can give me any design that you can think of. Also please ping me using @TheLizzard

Comment: @TheLizzard I made an approximation of the colorchooser class if you want to contribute and make it better.

https://github.com/Jake-Jasper/tkinter-colorpicker

Comment: @JLJ I will design and create my own one (I also want a colour wheel or something similar)

Comment: @TheLizzard Cool, let us know when it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand, it is not possible to modify the tkinter.colorchooser.askcolor as it uses the systems colorpicker dialog. Is this true?

Yes, that is true. At least on Windows and OSX. On Linux it's a [custom dialog written in tcl/tk](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/library/clrpick.tcl). You could start with that code and then make modifications to it, then write a tkinter wrapper around it. That wouldn't be particularly difficult if you know tcl/tk, but it's not exactly trivial either.

> Maybe it is possible to embed the dialog within a larger window?

No, it's not.

Comment: For those in the future that come across this, I made my own approximation of what the colorchooser function does that you can feel free to copy/improve

https://github.com/Jake-Jasper/tkinter-colorpicker